# What "cure" is Moore referring to?

Tags: dreamcatcher

Henry is driving the car and Moore is sitting in the 
passenger seat. Moore, who is holding his beer bottle, says to him:

> **MOORE:** *I know what you're thinking. **Anyone who drinks  at 11 a.m.
>   needs to take the cure**, but I only do it here. In the real world, I
>   never drink till after 5:00... and if it ever does, I'm on the wagon
>   for life.*

[image]

**What is the "cure" is Moore referring to and why would someone need it?**

Comment: Please stop asking basic language questions here. There is a site for that: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DanielRoseman - In this context it's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman There's no consensus that questions like this are off-topic; indeed, there's a [long-standing consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6596/31394) that questions about non-SFF elements in SFF works are *on-topic*. You may wish to take part in the [recent meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11626/31394) inspired by these questions, before telling users to take their questions elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to The Dictionary of American Slang, the term

> "Taking the cure"

refers to entering into an alcohol rehabilitation program.

Moore catches his friend giving him a look about grabbing a beer so early in the day. He replies to say that in when he's in his normal routine he'd never drink before 5pm but while they're on their annual trip he feels free to relax this personal rule.